# Does Bergman metric induce the standard topology?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

I am a physics student and am interested in the study of invariant metrics. I have searched several textbooks, including those fat books of Krantz, but the following concern seems not to be mentioned in these books.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be an open, bounded domain. In
literature, the Bergman distance between two points $z_{0}$ and $z_{1}$
(with $z_{0},z_{1}\in\Omega$) is defined by 
$$
d\left(z_{0},z_{1}\right):=\inf\left\{ l\left(\gamma\right):\gamma\in C^{1}\left(\left[0,1\right],\Omega\right),\gamma\left(0\right)=z_{0},\gamma\left(1\right)=z_{1}\right\} .
$$
Here 
$$
l\left(\gamma\right):=\intop_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial^{2}\left(\log K\left(\gamma\left(t\right),\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\right)}{\partial z_{j}\partial\overline{z}_{k}}\gamma'_{j}\left(t\right)\overline{\gamma'_{k}}\left(t\right)}dt,
$$
and $K$ denotes the Bergman kernel of $\Omega$.

My question:

Is $\left(\Omega,d\right)$ a metric space? If so, is the topology
induced by $d$ the standard topology on $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes it's a metric space; it's true more generally for any Riemannian metric. The second should be fine as well.

Comment: Yep, it's true for every distance induced by a Riemannian metric

Answer (score 2):

Let me convert my comment into an answer with references. It's easy to get distracted by the complicated formulas, but the key points are:

1. The Bergman kernel determines a Riemannian metric on $\Omega$ for which $d$ is the Riemannian distance. See chap 1 & 8 of *Helgason, Differential geometry, Lie groups and Symmetric spaces* for more details.
2. Both your questions have positive answers for Riemannian manifolds, cf. Helgason, pp 51-52.

Comment: You mean that these are true for any open, bounded domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ without any assumption on the smoothness of its boundary.

Comment: No, what happens on the boundary is not relevant for whether $d$ is a metric and for the topology it generates.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. All we need further is that $\Omega$ is connected so the definition makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that's right $\Omega$ should be connected.

Answer (score 1):

For the answer see the book by Jarnicki - Pflug: Invariant distances and metrics in complex analysis, 2nd edition, Corollary 12.9.7.